# Conversion between FileStream and log4net.Repository.ILoggerRepository UWP

Tags: c#, .net, logging, uwp, log4net

Hi I have a problem with log4net configuration in UWP because when I try to do this I get that I cannot convert FileInfo to ILoggerRepository

```
public MainPage()
        {
            XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo(Path.GetFileName("C:\\Users\\kamil\\source\repos\\Trader\\Trader\\Assets\\sample.xml")));
            this.InitializeComponent();
            ApiHelper.InitializeClient();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XmlConfigurator.Configure(FileInfo configFile)` in only available in .net framework. You should use `XmlConfigurator.Configure(ILoggerRepository repository, FileInfo configFile)` in order to make it work in your application. Here is an example:

```
ILoggerRepository loggerRepository = LogManager.GetRepository(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(Path.GetFileName(@"C:\Path\To\Source\sample.xml"));

XmlConfigurator.Configure(loggerRepository, fileInfo);
```

Full documentation: [XmlConfigurator.cs](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4net/blob/c04a774240fd4500ed3206124aba5b4bc8bc4933/src/Config/XmlConfigurator.cs)

Comment: Thank you, I have one more question could you tell me how to use this. I have my own configuration, but how can i log to file?